# Serviceworker and cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have an react-example of a service worker, with import statements.
Like:

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
```

If I use this code (react) in my service-worker, I get the message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at service-worker.js:1:1)
```

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bundle a service worker file that uses ES module imports, as they are [not supported in all service worker runtime environments](https://web.dev/es-modules-in-sw/#browser-support) at the moment.

The [Workbox documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/using-workbox-without-precaching/#when-using-a-bundler) has some more examples of this usage. Any bundler that supports ES modules should work; I tend to use [`esbuild`](https://esbuild.github.io/) nowadays.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I read many of the answers here on SO on how to integrate firebase-messaging-sw.js and service-worker.js used for PWA. Can you show an example based on this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651305/how-to-register-two-different-service-workers-in-the-same-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74651305/how-to-register-two-different-service-workers-in-the-same-scope)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Specifically, the poster has a service worker that uses ES module imports. The statement "You need to bundle a service worker file that uses ES module imports" is confusing. Am I missing something?