# How to register two different service-workers in the same scope?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a `service-worker.js` file to make my reactjs app PWA. I now also want to add push notification using FCM, which requires me to have `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in the public folder. So now for both to work both are going to require to be in the same scope.

But as far as I have read from various answers on this site, we can't have two different service workers in the same scope, so how do we combine both `service-worker.js` and `firebase-messaging-sw.js`  so both can function properly. One of the answers suggested that I rename the `service-worker.js` to `firebase-messaging-sw.js` which doesn't work. I did find one successful implementation on GitHub which I didn't understand much https://github.com/ERS-HCL/reactjs-pwa-firebase .

How can I have both the `service-worker.js` and `firebase-messaging-sw.js` work together?

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```js
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js");

 // Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing the generated config
 const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
    appId: "xxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxx"
}

 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 // Retrieve firebase messaging

const messaging = firebase.messaging();


self.addEventListener("notificationclick", function (event) {
  console.debug('SW notification click event', event)

  const url = event.notification.data.link
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then( windowClients => {
        // Check if there is already a window/tab open with the target URL
        for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
            var client = windowClients[i];
            // If so, just focus it.
            if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                return client.focus();
            }
        }
        // If not, then open the target URL in a new window/tab.
        if (clients.openWindow) {
            return clients.openWindow(url);
        }
    })
);
})


messaging.onBackgroundMessage(async function(payload) {
  console.log("Received background message ", payload)

  const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: payload.notification.body,
    icon: './logo192.png',
    badge: './notification-badgex24.png',
    data: {
        link: payload.data?.link
    }
  }

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions)

})
```

service-worker.js

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

clientsClaim();

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after spending weeks, I figured it out. So for anyone else, using the service worker created using the default create react app, follow the steps below.

first create `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in public folder and put the same code as in the question, but this time also add `importScripts("/service-worker.js")`.

```js
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js")
importScripts(`/service-worker.js`) // <- here notice this
.
.
.
```

The import will import the `service-worker.js` after the build step. The service worker you have in the src folder is only a template. You cannot use `importScript` in the `service-worker.js` file that's in the `src` folder as that will throw `importScripts is not defined` error.

Your build folder after your build step:

```
└── build/
    ├── static/
    │   ├── .
    │   ├── .
    │   └── .
    ├── index.html
    ├── firebase-messaging-sw.js
    ├── service-worker.js
    ├── .
    └── .
```

Now in index.html add

```html
 <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(reg => console.debug("Service worker registered sucessfully"))
    }
  
  </script>
```

And that's it. Both firebase-messaging and your PWA service worker will work

or you can also

You can create a new file called `sw.js` in your public folder and use `imporScript()` to import both `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and default `service-worker.js`

make sure to pass in service worker registration in `getToken` of the firebase

```
 const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        
 const currentToken = await getToken(messaging, { 
                                serviceWorkerRegistration: registration,
                                vapidKey: '<VAPID_KEY>' 
                            })
```

now simply register your new service worker in index file as shown

Comment: Could you please update this with your manifest.json?

Comment: @Aleka here I put it in paste bin: [https://pastebin.com/AXxDY3VR](https://pastebin.com/AXxDY3VR)

Comment: @Art thanks for the answer. I have tried your solution and it works, but after the initial registration of the service worker, your browser won't register it again (unless it got updated). So the promises of the registration will be gone and won't be able to use again inside the `getToken`, at least it is what happened to me after I refreshed the page. How can I solve it? To keep the initial registration promises so it can be later used over and over again when calling `getToken`?

Comment: @NoobCoder I didn't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean that the service worker is cached?

Comment: @Art let me simplify my question - your solution allows using any service worker that is registered on the site, lets call it `sw.js`. You wrote that "make sure to pass the registration in the `getToken` method". The problem is the regstiration happens only once (correct me if I'm wrong), only at the first time the user enters your site. After that - the service worker is already registered and even activated, so it won't register it again, which will lead to no "registration instance" that can be passed to the `getToken` method.

Comment: @NoobCoder It checks if the service-worker is already registered, it it isn't then it registers the service worker and returns a promise that resolves to [serviceWorkerRegistration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration). Here is a code you can refer: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KNLC3jjE) Let me know if you have any further question after going through the code.

Comment: @Art thanks for the explanation! So if we'll sum it up - is it correct to say that no matter what, the promise that resolves to serviceWorkerRegistration is returned either if the service worker is already registered or first registered.

Comment: @NoobCoder Yes, it is already registered or will register if the browser is compatible. Also don't forget to upvote if you found this helpful ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think one way of doing this is just having only firebase-messaging-sw.js file and using workbox to inject your service-worker.js into it

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/precaching-with-workbox/

forexample :

```
// build-sw.js
import {injectManifest} from 'workbox-build';

injectManifest({
  swSrc: './src/sw.js',
  swDest: './dist/firebase-messaging-sw.js',
  globDirectory: './dist',
  globPatterns: [
    '**/*.js',
    '**/*.css',
    '**/*.svg'
  ]
});
```

and all firebase config must be in sw.js to be written in firebase-messaging-sw.js

and in your package.json simply run build-sw.js before react-script start

```
     "scripts": {
        "start": "node build-sw.js && react-scripts start",
      }
```

or you can use [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) and [workbox box plugin](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/workbox/reference/workbox-webpack-plugin/) instead

Comment: Hey, thx for the answer, I have `importScripts()` in the `firebase-messaging-sw.js`. And it throws an error stating that `importScripts is not defined` when building the app. Do you happen to know why this would happen? Also, I updated the `serviceWorkerRegistration.js` to use `firebase-messaging-sw.js` instead of the default service-worker.js. Thank you agin.

Comment: Hi Ali, Do you happen to have an example so I can understand it easily?